# Length of time for waiting for hard cheese proportionate to the length of time it was aged

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, dairy

In a Halachic pamphlet I saw before Shavuos this year, it mentioned an opinion that one must wait after eating hard cheese one hour for every month it is aged (so if it was aged three months, three hours, etc.). It didn't say, but I assume that this means up to six hours, otherwise you could potentially wait [over a week](https://www.wisconsincheesemart.com/item/cheddar-15-year-half-loaf-Arq/#.VW54ds9VhBc) ...

This may or may not be tied in to the concern (also quoted in the same pamphlet) that modern artificial aging processes for cheese create hard cheese sooner than six months.

What is the source for this opinion, and what is the reasoning?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/dairy-that-you-have-to-wait-6-hours-after-eating-it